# Lock wait timeout exceeded; try restarting transaction when deleting data from table

Tags: mysql

I have created the following table.

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS  EMAILLIST_DETAILS (
            EMAIL_LIST_ID INTEGER,
            EMAIL VARCHAR(255),
            PRIMARY KEY (EMAIL_LIST_ID,EMAIL)
);
```

Then I am trying to delete email list by passing EMAIL_LIST_ID though my application by executing the below query.

```
DELETE FROM EMAILLIST_DETAILS WHERE EMAIL_LIST_ID=?
```

when executing this, it will throw the below error.

> ERROR 1205 (HY000): Lock wait timeout exceeded; try restarting transaction

How can I resolve this issue?

Comment: How long after? You can try increasing lock wait timeout.

Comment: That's a weird table structure. Does you table only have a composite primary key, and nothing more?

Answer (score 0):

As my experience, This can occur when trying to execute multiple queries (application side) like inserting, selecting, deleting. This kind of scenario may you can resolve by checking application side(BE).